# What is the reason updating a user's password fails in this Codeigniter 3 application?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am working on a basic **[blog application](https://github.com/Ajax30/lightblog/tree/password_reset_system)** in **Codeigniter 3.1.8** and Bootstrap 4.

I have added a **registration and login** system to this application. I am current working on a password reset system. It has a 2 steps process:

1. Generating a token and inserting it in the database (`authors`
   table).
2. Setting a new password.

Setting a new password fails with a 404 error for some reason I was unable to find out and fix.

The routes:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'posts';
$route['install'] = 'install';
$route['migrate'] = 'migrate';
$route['register'] = 'register';
$route['login'] = 'login';
$route['passwordreset'] = 'passwordreset';
$route['newpasword'] = 'newpasword';
$route['newpasword/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'newpasword/index/$1/$2/';
$route['dashboard'] = 'dashboard';
$route['dashboard/create-post'] = 'dashboard/posts/create';
$route['dashboard/create-page'] = 'dashboard/pages/create';
$route['dashboard/create-category'] = 'dashboard/categories/create';
$route['dashboard/manage-authors'] = 'dashboard/users';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['categories/posts/(:any)'] = 'categories/posts/$1';
$route['(:any)'] = 'posts/post/$1';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

In the Newpasword controller:

```
class Newpasword extends CI_Controller {

  private $hashed_email = '';
  private $token = '';

  public function index($hashed_email, $token) {
    $data = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();
    $data['pages'] = $this->Pages_model->get_pages();
    $data['tagline'] = 'New password';
    $data['categories'] = $this->Categories_model->get_categories();

    $this->hashed_email = $hashed_email;
    $this->token = $token;

    // Form validation rules
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[6]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cpassword', 'Confirm password', 'required|matches[password]');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error-message">', '</p>');

    if(!$this->form_validation->run()) {
        $this->load->view('partials/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('auth/newpassword');
        $this->load->view('partials/footer');
    } else {
        // Encrypt new password
      $enc_password = password_hash($this->input->post('password'), PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

      // Update password column
      $this->Usermodel->set_new_password($hashed_email, $token, $enc_password);
    }
  }
}
```

The view corresponding to the above controller (newpassword.php):

```
<?php echo form_open(base_url('newpassword')); ?>
  <div class="form-group <?php if(form_error('password')) echo 'has-error';?>">
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
    <?php if(form_error('password')) echo form_error('password'); ?> 
  </div>
  <div class="form-group <?php if(form_error('cpassword')) echo 'has-error';?>">
    <input type="password" name="cpassword" id="cpassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm password">
    <?php if(form_error('cpassword')) echo form_error('cpassword'); ?> 
  </div>
  <div class="form-group mb-2">
    <input type="submit" value="Set password" class="btn btn-block btn-md btn-success">
  </div>            
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

In the model I have the 2 methods for inserting the token and updating the password:

```
public function update_token($user_email, $reset_token) {
    $this->db
        ->where(['email' => $user_email])
        // insert token (make it diffrent from NULL)
        ->update('authors', array('token' => $reset_token));
}

public function set_new_password($hashed_email, $token, $enc_password) {
    $this->db
        ->where([md5('email') => $hashed_email])
        // set new password and reset token to NULL
        ->update('authors', array('password' => $enc_password, 'token' => NULL));
}
```

Inserting the token works without problems, but **setting a new password** fails with a **404** error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [HTTP Error 404](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) Check your routing

Comment: I did check it. It seems ok.

Comment: Just post relevant code which only contains **setting a new password**.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I can see is your code has a typo issue.

> Your route says `form_open(base_url('newpassword')); ?>` but you have defied them `$route['newpasword']`.

```
newpassword != newpasword
     ^^             ^^
```

**In route.php**

```
$route['newpasword'] = 'newpasword';
$route['newpasword/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'newpasword/index/$1/$2/';
```

---

And second `$route['newpasword/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'newpasword/index/$1/$2/';` we don't use  to send passwords in URL. It should be POST method and since you use `form_open` form create with `method="post"`. So in code `$_POST['password']` or [`$this->input->post()`](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/input.html#id4) will work

Answer (score 1):

After set the new password you redirect to **/newpasword** but the **index** function in **Newpasword** controller **only works with 2 parameter**. You need to create a new function in controller to view the success page (or redirect to main page with a session alert)

Comment: I think the `action` attribute of the form is incorrect, because it does not include the 2 parameters that the `index` method takes.

Comment: No, you previously modified the index method with 2 parameter to processing the new password link from email. Now this index method works with `$route['newpasword/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'newpasword/index/$1/$2/';` route.

Comment: Then, precisely because of that, should not I modify the `action` attribute of the form?

Comment: No, create a new function for success page and it is finished